# new XMLHttpRequest().responseType empty

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Why is `responseType` empty?

**JavaScript**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method,url,true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
 if (xhr.readyState=='4')
 {
  if (xhr.status==200)
  {
   console.log(xhr.responseType);//[empty]
  }
 }
}
```

**PHP**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//[Validated JSON Data]
```

No frameworks.

Comment: Empty means empty string?

Comment: a console.log of xhr shows the presence of responseType ?

Comment: Browser support is.... unknown: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType#Browser_compatibility

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType

It can be wmpty string

Comment: Been through all that. Empty string: `console.log(xhr.responseType);`.

Comment: I would avoid to use it, as @FelixKling states, unknown browser compatibility, it is creepy :)

Comment: Reading the spec it seems like *you* have to assign to this property before you send the request. Not sure if that information is sent to the server or if simply makes the client perform conversions on the response.

Comment: That's the kind of anti-intuitive nonsense I expect from CSS. Guess I'll have to use `getResponseHeader`. I'll determine the answer and post it so it'll save someone else the hassle and time of trying to figure out why yet another thing doesn't make logical sense. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As clarified in the comments the `new XMLHttpRequest().responseType` is intended as a request header and does not represent the media type/mime response from the server (which would have made logical sense). So to test for response types use something along the following lines:

**Full Media Type/Mime**

```
console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type'));//application/json
```

**Specific Media Type/Mime**

```
console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type').split('/')[1]);//json
```

Comment: Avoid splitting the header in case the server does not provide it, or provides a malformed type. Instead use `includes`, such as `xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type").includes("json")`. Additionally the server may return the encoding, thus splitting it will possibly result in `json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @NotoriousPyro Valid, I do object detection though I kept it simple here.